# On-demand Dynamic Feature module install always returns installed state but never downloads module

Tags: android, google-play-core, dynamic-feature-module

I use an on-demand dynamic feature module in my app and test ok with bundletool.jar. It can build apks from aab file. I upload to googleplay internal test. I try call `installManager.startInstall(request)` and googleplay service not download anything and always return installed state.

```
09-23 15:50:24.410   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallInfoProvider : App has no fused modules.
09-23 15:50:24.412   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallInfoProvider : Adding splits from package manager: [config.arm64_v8a]
09-23 15:50:24.424   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallListenerRegistry : registerListener
09-23 15:50:24.428   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallInfoProvider : App has no fused modules.
09-23 15:50:24.430   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallInfoProvider : Adding splits from package manager: [config.arm64_v8a]
09-23 15:50:24.432   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallInfoProvider : App has no fused modules.
09-23 15:50:24.433   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallInfoProvider : Adding splits from package manager: [config.arm64_v8a]
09-23 15:50:24.435   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallInfoProvider : App has no fused modules.
09-23 15:50:24.437   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallInfoProvider : Adding splits from package manager: [config.arm64_v8a]
09-23 15:50:24.438   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallService : startInstall([FaceDetect],[])
09-23 15:50:24.438   841  2131 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallService : Initiate binding to the service.
09-23 15:50:24.458   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.splitinstallservice.SplitInstallService})
09-23 15:50:24.458   841  2131 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallService : linkToDeath
09-23 15:50:24.495   841  2131 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallService : Unbind from service.
09-23 15:50:24.495   841  1572 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallService : onStartInstall(0)
09-23 15:50:24.501  1426  1426 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [1426] SplitInstallListenerRegistry : ListenerRegistryBroadcastReceiver.onReceive: SplitInstallSessionState{sessionId=0, status=5, errorCode=0, bytesDownloaded=0, totalBytesToDownload=0, moduleNamesNullable=[FaceDetect], languagesNullable=null, resolutionIntent=null, splitFileIntents=null}
09-23 15:50:24.505   841   841 I PlayCore: UID: [10663]  PID: [841] SplitInstallListenerRegistry : unregisterListener
```

Comment: I am sure the module is not exist,why google play tell me it was installed.